# How to set Application Variable in SignalR Hub class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-2

First of all I know that we can not access Session Variable and Application Variable in `SignalR`. But my requirement is I want to increase or decrease current logged in user count from SignalR `OnConnect()` and `OnDisconnect()` method.
That I already did using below code.

**SignalR Hub Class :-**

```
public  class  SampleHub : Hub
{
     // Use this variable to track user count
     private  static  int _userCount = 0;

     // Public hub methods  
    :

     // Overridable hub methods  
     public  override Task OnConnected()
    {
       _userCount ++; // this I want to set in Application variable
    }
     public  override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        _userCount ++; // this I want to set in Application variable
    }
     public  override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
       _userCount --; // this I want to set in Application variable
    }
}
```

After setting values in `_userCount` variable When another user logged into the system. In Login button click event I want to check `if _userCount >= 11` then show message

**"YOU HAVE REACHED MAXIMUM CONCURRENT USER LOG IN LIMIT !"**

But I am not able to use Application variable into SignalR - So **My Question is** How can I make access of `_userCount` variable in `Login.aspx.cs` or any other `.aspx.cs` page.
Can I call any server method from SignalR Hub ?

any help will be greatly appreciated !

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your _userCount variable public and add reference of SampleHub class to Login.aspx.cs or any other cs page you want to and access your _userCount variable.

```
public static int _userCount=0;
```

On Login.aspx.cs page use it like this :

```
int usercount = SampleHub._userCount;
```

Hope this will help you